# How override the global AuthorizeAttribute when add same AuthorizeAttribute for some Action MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my CustomAuthorizeAttribute class:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

       public string ControllerName { get; set; }


      public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
      {
           if (ControllerName != "pass")
           {
            // stop or redirect
           }

      }
}
```

I register it to global filters for all controller can use:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
      filters.Add(new AdminAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

For some specific Action I add it with the param **ControllerName** :

```
[AdminAuthorize(ControllerName="pass")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return View();
}
```

But the problem is now in the **OnAuthorization()**, the **ControllerName** is always get **null** when execute the specific Action.

Is that because I can't use the global authorizeAttribute and same Attibute for some specific Action **together**??  Why?  I always thought if I add some AuthorizeAttribute for specific Action, and add the Attribute to global filter , the specific Action will get **height priority**.

**Update1:**

If the problem source is 2 authorized all execute. then How do I **override the global authorized filter** when I add a same AuthorizeAttribute for Some Action? (only different is the param, I just want it ignore the global authorized when I add one for some Action)

Comment: you can change the Order property of the attribute manually, so that it will be fired first.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with combination of Order property and marking in context items that the request has been authorized by on of my attributes:

```
public class AuthorizeByRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string AuthorizedContextItemName = "_AuthorizedByRoles";

    public AuthorizeByRolesAttribute (params string[] roles)
    {
        this.Order = 0;
        this.Roles = string.Join (",", roles);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization (AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items[AuthorizedContextItemName] != null)
            return;

        base.OnAuthorization (filterContext);

        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items[AuthorizedContextItemName] = this.Roles ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In global configs:

```
filters.Add (new AuthorizeByRolesAttribute ("Admin"), 255);
```

In controller simply:

```
[AuthorizeByRoles ("NotAdminButCanAccess")]
public class MyController : Controller
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to Order property on the custom attribute, so that it will be fired first:

```
[AdminAuthorize(ControllerName="pass", Order=999)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return View();
}
```

this is an example offcourse.

And yes, you can override global filters this way.

Comment: thanks. but Can I just set the order to the global filter? then I don't need set order for every specific Action.

Comment: Yes, set a default value in the default constructor and create an overload constructor with custom value

Comment: I'm register global filter use ``filters.Add(new AdminAuthorizeAttribute(), 1);``  looks like the order min number is height priority, please edit your answer. but now the problem is : it not override the global filter, the 2 filter all will execute.....